# If I power a motherboard without CPU/RAM, what will happen?

Tags: motherboard

First, I know it won't get through POST. No RAM/CPU make that fairly obvious. There is a 2-digit seven segment debug display on the board. (It's an ASRock Z77 Extreme4.) Can I expect any of the following, if the motherboard is good?

- The 2-digit 7-seg display to have some diagnostic code, probably something along the lines of "No CPU"
- Power LEDs on the board itself (if they exist) to light?
- Whirs or full-action from case fans or PSU fans?

  ...basically, some sign of life.

I'm looking for some way to isolate and test just the board itself.

The PSU looks okay: shorting the green wire to a ground I was able to power fans, and a DVD drive that seemed to be endlessly resetting itself (probably due to there not being anyone on the other side of the SATA cable).

Also good to know: Would powering it up without a CPU/RAM damage the motherboard? I can't see why it would, but you never know...

Comment: Typically with missing ram and/or CPU, you'll get system beeps (old school -> 3 beeps for bad/missing memory)

Comment: @kobaltz, yep, with speaker attached or an on-motherboard speaker, the motherboard just complains loudly at you, just not as interestingly as R2D2.

Comment: Well, I tried it with just the main motherboard power cable attached (not the CPU power connector) and got nothing. So I went from there and installed the CPU (and connected the power connector) & a single stick of RAM (twice, with two different ones, as I have two RAM modules), and still nothing. Something is horked, but I don't know what.

Comment: Depending on manufacturer, it probably beeps at you a lot if there's an onboard speaker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to answer this as it happened for me:

> - The 2-digit 7-seg display to have some diagnostic code, probably something along the lines of "No CPU"

For this specific motherboard, *sigh*, no such luck.

> - Power LEDs on the board itself (if they exist) to light?

Again, not that I remember.

> - Whirs or full-action from case fans or PSU fans?

***Yes***. The case fans did indeed spin up, and the DVD drive started attempting to spin up the nonexistent disc in it. (and appeared to proceed to put itself in a reset loop, presumably because it couldn't find anyone to talk to.)

One more thing: the purpose of this was to find out if my PSU or my motherboard was at fault, as nothing powered up when connected normally.

**Despite getting signs of life from the non-mobo case components attached to the PSU, *the PSU was at fault***.

The fact that I *got* signs of life when I shorted the PSU's motherboard connection lead me to believe that the motherboard was at fault. (When the whole thing was connected, nothing powered up.) In my case, this was a mistake.

If you're debugging hardware, I highly recommend seeing a component work with a known-good setup in a full configuration before declaring it good; in my case, I didn't narrow in on the PSU until I swapped it out for a known good PSU, and everything else started functioning perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Booting a motherboard without RAM should cause beep codes.

However, from the few motherboards Ive powered that had no processors, no beep codes were generated.

Comment: I've done this with a dual-processor server missing processor 1, and it did give a beep code (this was a server motherboard with a second processor installed, but the manual indicated that it was a generic "no processor installed" code - processor 1 [removed] was apparently mandatory, and processor 2 [installed] couldn't fill its role)

Comment: @cpast many multi-cpu motherboards use a "blank" to put in those slots.  The blank has a few pins on it that tell the mobo there is no cpu here.